# How to change image resolution multiple time during my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, resolution, opencv

i want to be able to change my image resolution durring my code:

```
import cv2

def make_720p():
    cap.set(3, 1280)
    cap.set(4, 720)

def make_480p():
    cap.set(3, 640)
    cap.set(4, 480)

make_720p()

while True:

    rect, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

time.sleep(1)
make_480p()

while True:

    rect, frame1 = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame1)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

assume i press 'q' to enter the second loop.
that doesnt work.. what can i do?
do i can downscale the resolution without taking new picture?

Comment: Try recreating the `cv2.VideoCapture` object before you enter the second loop.

Comment: Thanks! problem solve.